# Styled-components props от родителя компонента

Tags: reactjs

Родительский компонент:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ChildComponent/>
      )
  }
}
```

Дочерний компонент:

```
const Hello = styled.div`
  color: ${ props => props.positive?'white':'black'};
  background: ${ props => props.positive?'green':'red' };
`;
class ChildComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Hello>
                HELLO
            </Hello>
        );
    }
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

Если я пишу `<Hello positive>`, то всё работает, `<ChildComponent positive>` не работает.
Как произвести кастомизацию из родительского компонента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если написать в родительском классе код следующим образом:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <ChildComponent positive />
      )
  }
}
```

То в дочернем компоненте `ChildComponent` в `props` появится значение `positive: true`, то есть, его нужно из `props` компонента `ChildComponent` пробросить в ваш компонент `Hello`. Пример кода:

```
const Hello = styled.div`
  color: ${ props => props.positive?'white':'black'};
  background: ${ props => props.positive?'green':'red' };
`;

class ChildComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Hello positive={this.props.positive}>
                HELLO
            </Hello>
        );
    }
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

Тогда в вашем компоненте `Hello` в `props` появится значение `positive: true`. Чтобы изменить `true` на `false` нужно в родителе прописать код следующим образом:

```
<ChildComponent positive={false} />
```

Comment: да, действительно так.